# Adding drain to existing system

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent

I'm looking to add a drain line for a new water softener to my existing drainage system. It happens that where I'd like to install the new drain is right on the other side of the wall from an existing bathroom, and I'd like to tap into the drain line for the tub.

Here's what I'm thinking of doing:
[image: Adding new drain line to existing drainage]

Is adding the extra line like this necessary, or could I perhaps go directly into the existing tub line via a sanitary-tee? I think it's required that I have the new trap for the stand-pipe since they're different fixture types (as opposed to something like a double-basin sink), which is why I'm thinking this way is correct.

Assuming the extra trap/line are needed, is the wet venting in the diagram sufficient?

Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's an S-Trap (somewhat elongated) as drawn. Depending on pipe sizes and your specific area's code, there are ways to make it legit, or there are not. See "single-stack" in the IPC plumbing code, for an example. In my area, that's the code, but that section is forbidden/struck from adopted code. https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-9-vents#IPC2018_Ch09_Sec917

Comment: Hmm, I see. Is the fact that it has that second vertical drop (even though it's after a horizontal span) what makes it the prohibited S-Trap? Is the difference from the existing line because the vent is @ the top of the vertical section, vs. there being a drop before the vent line? I've been reading through IPC 1002.1 and I think I might be better off modifying it to look something like this instead: https://i.imgur.com/FLI8eVD.png

Comment: You've actually got 2 traps in your new drain line. The first one is just below the softener drain line. The second one is created by the horizontal wye on the right hand side of the drawing, assuming, of course that it does actually go back up hill there.

Answer (score 0):

According to all the existing codes that I am aware of, you can not connect the drain line from the water softner directly into a sanitary drain. In all cases, you must use what is called an "air gap" to insure that the water in the drain pipe can never contaminate your domestic water. By doing the connection the way you describe, if there is a back-up of water or a problem with the water softner, you could contaminate your water supply with whatever is in that existing drain line. My softner drains into the laundry tubs with a line that terminates just below the rim of the tub.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I plan to install the air gap at the top of the standpipe. I'll add that into the diagram to make it clear. I'm concerned about the trap placement & venting here though.